# Excel : Alternatively Change Cell Color as Cell Value Changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed an Excel Real-Time Data Feed (RTD) to monitor Stock Prices as they arrive.
I Would like to find a way to change the color of a cell as prices change.
For example, a cell initially Green would turn to Red when the value changes (new price occurred on it via RTD Formula it contains) and then change back to Green when a new price arrives, and so on...

Comment: Why not use conditional formatting?  It would mean that you are not relying on the user enabling macros.

Comment: Try to go further concretely with conditional formatting : I think it is a no go as it is value based (greater, less, equal, etc.) and I found no way to to do what I want as I just want to track "any" change on the cells.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can get you started?
I supose a event is raised when the real time data is refreshed.
the concept sis to store the real time data in a variabele and check if it has changed

```
 Dim rtd As String

 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
        If .Value <> rtd Then
            Select Case .Interior.ColorIndex
                Case 2
                    .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Case 3
                    .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                Case 4
                    .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Case Else
                    .Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            End Select
        Else
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 2

        End If
        rtd = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a shot and keep you posted. I hope it won't overload performance :-)

Comment: I don't know how to generalize your proposition to "N" cells as I have a whole sheet full of RTD cells. Ideally I would like to detect changes on any cell not just a particular one

Comment: Maybe u can use a (hidden) sheet to witch you copy the old values before update and then use conditional formatting to display the changes.

Comment: `Worksheet_SelectionChange` is called when then selection changes, not when values chane.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal ChangedCell As Range)

  ' This routine is called whenever the user changes a cell.
  ' It is not called if a cell is changed by Calculate.

  Dim ColChanged As Integer
  Dim RowChanged As Integer

  ColChanged = ChangedCell.Column
  RowChanged = ChangedCell.Row

  With ActiveSheet
    If .Cells(RowChanged, ColChanged).Interior.ColorIndex = 19 Then
      ' Changed cell is red.  Set it to green.
      .Cells(RowChanged, ColChanged).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    Else
      ' Changed cell is not red.  Set it to red.
      .Cells(RowChanged, ColChanged).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    End If
  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution reposonds to a `Calculation` event.  I am not entirely sure if an RTD update triggers this, so you will need to experiment.

Add this code to the `Worksheet` module containing your RTD calls.

It keeps a copy of the sheet data in memory from the last calculation, and on each calc compares new values.
It limits its action to cells containing your formula.

```
Option Explicit

Dim vData As Variant
Dim vForm As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim vNewData As Variant
    Dim vNewForm As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    If IsArray(vData) Then
        vNewData = Me.UsedRange
        vNewForm = Me.UsedRange.Formula
        For i = LBound(vData, 1) To UBound(vData, 1)
        For j = LBound(vData, 2) To UBound(vData, 2)
            ' Change this to match your RTD function name
            If vForm(i, j) Like "=YourRTDFunction(*" Then  
                If vData(i, j) <> vNewData(i, j) Then
                    With Me.Cells(i, j).Interior
                        If .ColorIndex = 3 Then
                            .ColorIndex = 4
                        Else
                            .ColorIndex = 3
                        End If
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next j, i
    End If
    vData = Me.UsedRange
    vForm = Me.UsedRange.Formula

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the previous answer assume that Real-time data feed triggers worksheet events.  I can find nothing in the RTD documents to confirm or deny this assumption.  However, if it does trigger worksheet events, I would have thought that Worksheet_Change would have been the most useful since it identifies a cell that has changed.

The following might be worth trying.  It must be placed in the code area for the relevant worksheet.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal ChangedCell As Range)

  ' This routine is called whenever the user changes a cell.
  ' It is not called if a cell is changed by Calculate.

  Dim ColChanged As Integer
  Dim RowChanged As Integer

  ColChanged = ChangedCell.Column
  RowChanged = ChangedCell.Row

  With ActiveSheet  
    If .Cells(RowChanged, ColChanged).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) then 
      ' Changed cell is red.  Set it to green.
      .Cells(RowChanged, ColChanged).Font.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Else
      ' Changed cell is not red.  Set it to red.
      .Cells(RowChanged, ColChanged).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for same. My scenario was like change the color of cell when value is select from list. Each list item corresponds for a color.

What eventually worked for me is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Set MyPlage = Range("B2:M50")

    For Each Cell In MyPlage

        Select Case Cell.Value

         Case Is = "Applicable-Incorporated"

            Cell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 128, 0)
        Case Is = "Applicable/Not Incorporated"
            Cell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 204, 0)

        Case Is = "Not Applicable"
            Cell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 128, 0)

        Case Else
            Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

        End Select

    Next

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, the most simple is this code :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 ': yellow
End Sub
```