# Change formatting of Cell when it is edited

Tags: vba, excel

I want to change the formatting of a cell if the value changes. I just need it to be shaded in.

I'm trying to use the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
End Sub
```

However this is far too sensitive. For example if i delete a row, the entire row changes colour as technically it's a change. Even if I go into a cell, make no change and come out of it, it changes the formatting.

Is there anyway to edit the above so it only formats the cell's when the value has changed?

Thanks

Comment: What if a cell is cleared? How many cells can be changed in one operation? Literally speaking, deleting a row or column changes the value of all cells within the row or column within the used range.

Comment: I might be looking for an ideal that just isn't possible. But if a Cell previously had nothing in it, and someone selected it and pressed backspace, it wouldn't format the cell. However if there was something in the cell before pressing backspace, then it would format it. Only 1 Cell will be edited at a time. It would be ideal if it would only format a cell if the value that is in it has changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel : Alternatively Change Cell Color as Cell Value Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567833/excel-alternatively-change-cell-color-as-cell-value-changes)

Comment: Try searching for "Worksheet_Change" in the StackOverflow search. Pretty good answers would pop-up. https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=Worksheet_Change

Comment: Can a range of edits be limited or does it have to be the entire worksheet?

Comment: It can be a range, generally, no edits will be made outside of A1:Z150

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use below code as a base for your further logic.

The idea is: we need to remember value before it is changed, so best to read it when some range is selected (since you are talking about single cell, I didn't consider ranges consisting of more cells). The value would be stored in global variable `ValueOnEnter`.

When the change is finally made, we compare values "before" and after", and if they differ, change the color.

```
Public ValueOnEnter As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value <> ValueOnEnter Then
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    ValueOnEnter = Target.Value
End Sub
```